# How to change Title (Top) size on arrangeGrob?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, title, gridextra

I have already written a ggplot function and managed to get a multiplot with 12 plots. Therefore i need a overall title, which is already added. The problem is that it is way to small and i can`t find the function to change it.
my code is:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(grobs=scatterplots, widths= c(1,1,1), 
             layout_matrix = rbind(c(1,2,3),
                                   c(4,5,6),
                                   c(7,8,9),
                                   c(10,11,12))),
             left="hourly ET observed [mm]",
             bottom="hourly ET gap filled [mm]",
             top="gap filled by")
```

Comment: Try using the `patchwork` package: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/annotation.html See the command `plot_annotation(title = "Overall title")`

Comment: but how can i combine this package with the previous code?

Comment: `pachwork` offers a very simple alternative to `grid.arrange`; you need to change your code but with a little effort

Comment: `top = grid::textGrob('title', gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=24))`

Comment: is there a way to adept this to the left without changing it from vertical to horizontal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was provided by user baptiste:

```
top = grid::textGrob('title', gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=24))
```